# GUI for managing system services - is there any?

Tags: system, gui-toolkits

Is there any "native" Elementary OS graphical utility to manage system services/daemons? I mean easy and nice tool to start, stop, enable, disable, check status of a webserver, MySQL server, sshd and so on.

I have searched, but I have found only some deb packages outside regular EOS repository, which I am not sure should integrate well and shouldn't spoil the system(d) ;)

TYIA,
Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not official, this might work for you
https://github.com/Dirli/switchboard-plug-services

Integrated into system settings

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!